# React props being mutated before setState called (react-beautiful-dnd)

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm having a strange issue when implementing a drag-and-drop. The drag and drop has 2 levels, the Group and the Rank.

The intention is that every "overall group" (buttons at the top) maintain their own ranks for both Groups and Ranks. So if I move `Type A - 1` to Rank 2 when I have `Overall Group A` selected, I should be able to then select `Overall Group B` and see `Type A - 1` in rank 1.

The Group (outer) level works fine. When I change between "Overall" groups, the sorting remains tied to each respective overall group as seen below:

[image: good example]

However when changing the Rank it changes for *all* overall groups. Even stranger, when console logging before my `setState` (passed through props) I can see the props are already changed before calling! Somehow my props (and actually the state) object is being mutated before I call `setState`.

[image: bad example]

A couple things I tried:

1. smacking `key` everywhere and making them unique, in case this is a DnD problem
2. making copies of the props before ever passing it to a Draggable or a function that could potentially mutate it

I did make a codesandbox -- https://codesandbox.io/s/react-beautiful-dnd-nested-drag-bug-q89lot?file=/src/Wrapper.tsx:1649-2116

but functionally both Draggable's reuse a single `onDragEnd` which does some logic to then call `setOverallGroups()` which sets the groups and ranks for all groups at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shallow copying only clone the top level only. So if you have a nested object then it will not clone them.

```
  const listsInitalState: OverallGroup = {
    "Type A": typeAItems,
    "Type B": typeBItems,
    Order: ["Type A", "Type B"]
  };

  const shallowCpy = {...listsInitialState};

  console.log(shallowCpy["Type A"] === listsInitialState["Type A"]) // this will be true
```

Therefore you should do a [deep](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Deep_copy) copy. Another way to do a deep copy is use the lodash `cloneDeep` method.

**Another Solution,**

Since you are using the same data for all the tabs, keep the data in single place and manage the order of the items by ids of the data objects,

```
const [order, setOrder] = useState({
  1: { // an unique id for each overall group
    0: { // unique id to identify each groups within overall group
      subOrder: [0,2,1,3] // order of the group with id 0
    },
    1: {
      subOrder: [0,3,1,2]
    }
  },
  // rest of the overllgroup ids
})
```

Then use the `order` to render items & content will be not mutated in this way as well as you will not clone bunch of data as well.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-beautiful-dnd-nested-drag-bug-forked-i8x5ry?file=/src/Wrapper.tsx

In short, you are **shallow cloning** your `listsInitalState` across "overall groups". You want to **deep clone** them, so that any changes (of any level) in one "overall groups" doesn't affect other groups.

In your `Wrapper.tsx`, you should use deep cloning at these lines of code:

```
const [overallGroups, setOverallGroups] = useState<
  Record<string, OverallGroup>
>({
  'Overall Group A': JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(listsInitalState)),
  'Overall Group B': JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(listsInitalState)),
  'Overall Group C': JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(listsInitalState)),
  'Overall Group D': JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(listsInitalState)),
  'Overall Group E': JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(listsInitalState)),
});
```

...instead of shallow cloning:

```
const [overallGroups, setOverallGroups] = useState<
  Record<string, OverallGroup>
>({
  'Overall Group A': { ...listsInitalState },
  'Overall Group B': { ...listsInitalState },
  'Overall Group C': { ...listsInitalState },
  'Overall Group D': { ...listsInitalState },
  'Overall Group E': { ...listsInitalState },
});
```

Note: My solution uses `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` as the simplest way to do deep-cloning for simple objects. It is not very performant, however, so you can look into third-party libraries, or if your environment already supports, you can use [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone).